# Python How to skip the part in a string marked by certain symbols？

Tags: python

I‘m trying to reconstruct a sentence by one-to-one matching the words in a word list to a sentence:

```
text='acatisananimal'
words=['cat','is','an','a','animal']

for i in words:
    if i in text:
        final=text.replace(i,' '+i)
        text=final
print(final)
```

the expected output will be like:

```
a cat is an animal
```

If I run my code, the 'a' and 'an' in 'animal' will be unavoidably separated too.
So I want to sort the word list by the length, and search for the long words first.

```
words.sort(key=len)
words=words[::-1]
```

Then I would like to mark the long words with special symbols, and expect the program could skip the part I marked. For example:

```
acatisan%animal&
```

And finally I will erase the symbols. But I'm stuck here. I don't know what to do to make the program skip the certain parts between '%' and '&' . Can anyone help me?? Or are there better ways to solve the spacing problem? Lots of Thanks!

**For another case，what if the text include the words that are not included in the word list？How could I handle this？

```
text=‘wowwwwacatisananimal’
```

Comment: What is the current output you are getting?

Comment: @t.m.adam Well yes, I know. But when I used defined in the context of my comment, I was asking is `final` initialized _anywhere_. But yes, your entirely right.

Comment: [My solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43366440/5811078) works in that case as well.

Answer (score 3):

A more generalized approach would be to look for all valid words at the beginning, split them off and explore the rest of the letters, e.g.:

```
def compose(letters, words):
    q = [(letters, [])]
    while q:
        letters, result = q.pop()
        if not letters:
            return ' '.join(result)
        for word in words:
            if letters.startswith(word):
                q.append((letters[len(word):], result+[word]))

>>> words=['cat','is','an','a','animal']
>>> compose('acatisananimal', words)
'a cat is an animal'
```

If there are potentially multiple possible sentence compositions it would trivial to turn this into a generator and replace `return` with `yield` to yield all matching sentence compositions.

Contrived example (just replace `return` with `yield`):

```
>>> words=['adult', 'sex', 'adults', 'exchange', 'change']
>>> list(compose('adultsexchange', words))
['adults exchange', 'adult sex change']
```

Comment: Sorry I’m a beginner of python and I'm using python3. This program turns out to have some trouble printing. It prints a lot of lists containing many brackets and quotes. Could you help me with printing a pretty result? Thank you!

Comment: It seems like it is printing every steps. I've tried to put the printing argument out side the loop but it gives stranger outputs

Comment: You should need to print the result of the function, e.g. `print(compose('...', words))`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can replace the word with the index, so the `final` string should be like this `3 0 1 2 4` and then convert it back to sentence:

```
text='acatisananimal'
words=['cat','is','an','a','animal']


for i in sorted(words,key=len,reverse=True):
    if i in text:
        final=text.replace(i,' %s'%words.index(i))
        text=final
print(" ".join(words[int(i)] for i in final.split()))
```

Output:

```
a cat is an animal
```

Comment: To some extent, I think this way is not very good, it maybe returns unexpected result, I will continue to find a better solution.

Comment: When capital letters appear it will report an error, I could create another list with all words capitalized. It's quite effective. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need a small modification in your code, update the code line

```
final=text.replace(i,' '+i)

to
```

`final=text.replace(i,' '+i, 1)` . This will replace only the first occurrence.

So the updated code would be

```
text='acatisananimal'
words=['cat','is','an','a','animal']
for i in words:
if i in text:
    final=text.replace(i,' '+i, 1)
    text=final
print(final)
```

Output is:

```
a cat is an animal
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting on that part of removing only the symbols...then regex is your what you are looking for..import a module called re and do this.

```
import re
code here
print  re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', final)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using different delimeters either side of your matched words(`%` and `&` in your example.)

It's easier to use the same delimiter either side of your marked word and use Python's list slicing.

The solution below uses the `[::n]` syntax for getting every `n`th element of a list.

`a[::2]` gets even-numbered elements, `a[1::2]` gets the odd ones.

```
>>> fox = "the|quick|brown|fox|jumpsoverthelazydog"
```

Because they have `|` characters on either side, `'quick'` and `'fox'` are odd-numbered elements when you split the string on `|`:

```
>>> splitfox = fox.split('|')
>>> splitfox
['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumpsoverthelazydog']
>>> splitfox[1::2]
['quick', 'fox']
```

and the rest are even:

```
>>> splitfox[::2]
['the', 'brown', 'jumpsoverthelazydog']
```

So, by enclosing known words in `|` characters, splitting, and scanning even-numbered elements, you're searching only those parts of the text that are not yet matched. This means you don't match within already-matched words.

```
from itertools import chain


def flatten(list_of_lists):
    return chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists)


def parse(source_text, words):
    words.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    texts = [source_text, '']  # even number of elements helps zip function
    for word in words:
        new_matches_and_text = []
        for text in texts[::2]:
            new_matches_and_text.append(text.replace(word, f"|{word}|"))
        previously_matched = texts[1::2]
        # merge new matches back in
        merged = '|'.join(flatten(zip(new_matches_and_text, previously_matched)))
        texts = merged.split('|')
    # remove blank words (matches at start or end of a string)
    texts = [text for text in texts if text]
    return ' '.join(texts)

>>> parse('acatisananimal', ['cat', 'is', 'a', 'an', 'animal'])
'a cat is an animal'
>>> parse('atigerisanenormousscaryandbeautifulanimal', ['tiger', 'is', 'an',  'and', 'animal'])
'a tiger is an enormousscary and beautiful animal'
```

The `merge` code uses the `zip` and `flatten` functions to splice the new matches and old matches together. It basically works by pairing even and odd elements of the list, then "flattening" the result back into one long list ready for the next word.

This approach leaves the unrecognised words in the text.

`'beautiful'` and `'a'` are handled well because they're on their own (i.e. next to recognised words.)

`'enormous'` and `'scary'` are not known and, as they're next to each other, they're left stuck together.

Here's how to list the unknown words:

```
>>> known_words = ['cat', 'is', 'an', 'animal']
>>> sentence = parse('anayeayeisananimal', known_words)
>>> [word for word in sentence.split(' ') if word not in known_words]
['ayeaye']
```

I'm curious: is this a bioinformatics project?

Comment: Thank you very much! It is helpful. It is just simply a word reconstruction assignment. I found it really hard for a beginner like me to figure it out :(

Comment: Hi @toyhtoza, ok then my method is overkill indeed! But I wondered, because why would you bother reconstructing sentences that have lost the spaces between words? It didn't seem like a real-world problem.

Comment: It's not beginner's code: that's why I put in some explanations. It will take some effort to understand. Note that you don't need to understand `flatten`, which is just a useful utility I took from  https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html. I think the rest of the code you will understand if you step through line by line and look at the intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

List and dict comprehension is another way to do it:

```
result = ' '.join([word for word, _ in sorted([(k, v) for k, v in zip(words, [text.find(word) for word in words])], key=lambda x: x[1])])
```

So, I used `zip` to combine words and their position in text, `sorted` the words by their position in original text and finally joined the result with `' '`.

Comment: `Simple is better than complex.` (from https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: @boardrider Comprehension is a very fast and pythonic way of solving loops. Do you have a suggestion for making it better?

Comment: While it's true that list comprehension is fast, performance doesn't seem to be a concern here, @zipa - and as I noted in my quote from the _Zen of Python,_ it's preferable (and Pythonic) to use a *simple to understand* syntax, rather than the almost incomprehensible long comprehension that you suggested.